# How to extract last set of parentheses in a string

Tags: python, regex

I have a very long list of strings and I need to capture the last character or characters. For simple strings `"axa"`, `"lmn"`, `str[0]` works.

Some cases the last character could be either of 2 for example for string "`qa(n|m)` ,
the last character could be `n` or `m`. so I need to capture the last set of parentheses in a string and get all contents within that.
In this case , `re.search('\((.*?)\)',s).group(1)` gives the contents. However, if that string has 2 sets of parentheses, then it doesnt work.

for example : `if str= "aaa(2)bbb(n|m)"` , I need only `'n|m'`

appreciate any help.

Comment: Loop through with an interator: `for m in re.finditer('\(([^)]+)\)', s): pass` then `m.group(1)` has the last match at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presuming the substring is always at the end, you can find the rightmost `(` and slice to the end -1:

```
s = "aaa(2)bbb(n|m)"

print(s.rstrip("*")[s.rfind("(")+1:-1])
n|m
```

Or using re just use findall and get the last element:

```
import re

print(re.findall('\((.*?)\)',s)[-1])
```

`rstrip` will remove the `*` if it as the end of the string or else do nothing.

```
In [24]: s = "ee(1)bb(aaa|bbb)*"
In [25]: print(s.rstrip("*")[s.rfind("(")+1:-1])
aaa|bbb
In [26]: print(re.findall('\((.*?)\)',s)[-1])
aaa|bbb    
In [27]: s = "ee(1)bb(aaa|bbb)"    
In [28]: print(re.findall('\((.*?)\)',s)[-1])
aaa|bbb    
In [29]: print(s.rstrip("*")[s.rfind("(")+1:-1])
aaa|bbb
```

Comment: thanks this works ! but any idea how I can get rid of the last ')' from the result. "s="ee(1)bb(aaa|bbb)*" gives  'aaa|bbb)'. I would like to exclude that in the same step if possible.

Comment: The easiest way is to slap a `[:-1]` on the end of the string.

Comment: @AmritaSawant. Do you have other characters after the final `)`?

Comment: I see the string is now `"...bbb)*"`, with a character after the closing parenthesis. If that's not always there, then there's more processing to do.

Comment: yeah there can be a ' * '

Comment: @AmritaSawant, then just use rstrip, it will remove the `*` if it exists.

Answer (score 2):

With `rpartition()` and `partition()`:

```
>>> "aaa(2)bbb(n|m)".rpartition('(')[2].partition(')')[0]
'n|m'
```

If the closing parenthesis is always the last character in the string, you can replace `.partition(')')[0]` with `[:-1]`:

```
>>> "aaa(2)bbb(n|m)".rpartition('(')[2][:-1]
'n|m'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pure regex approach to do this with this regex:

```
\(([^)]+)\)[^)]*\Z
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sG7xM6/2)

In Python:

```
>>>> s=''.join(["aaa(2)bbb(n|m{})".format(i) for i in range(5001)])
```

(that makes a long string `aaa(2)bbb(n|m0)` up to `aaa(2)bbb(n|m5000)`)

```
>>> import re
>>>> re.search(r'\(([^)]+)\)[^)]*\Z', s).group(1)
'n|m5000'
```

The advantage is that only one match is made rather than building an entire list of every match as `re.findall` would do.

Anchored matches are *usually* faster too.

If you want to be even faster, but at the cost of readability, you can do this:

1. Reverse the string;
2. Match the FIRST set of inside out parenthesis;
3. Reverse the match.

Demo:

```
>>>> re.search(r'^[^)]*\)([^(]+)\(', s[::-1]).group(1)[::-1]
'n|m5000'
```

Timing these:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit("re.findall('\((.*?)\)',s)[-1]", setup="from __main__ import s, re", number=1000)
2.9381589889526367000
>>> timeit.timeit("re.search(r'\(([^)]+)\)[^)]*\Z', s).group(1)", setup="from __main__ import s, re", number=1000)
1.588352918624878
>>> timeit.timeit("re.search(r'^[^)]*\)([^(]+)\(', s[::-1]).group(1)[::-1]", setup="from __main__ import s, re", number=1000)
0.27100610733032227
```

You can see the reverse string method is about 10x or 6X faster than the other two methods...